# Difference Between Lowest Level and Last Level in A Binary Tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Is the Root of a Binary Tree the Lowest Level or are the Leaves Lowest Level.

The elements 71, 65, 84, 69, 67, 83 are inserted in a binary search tree. The element in the
lowest level is?

Answer (score 2):

Trees in computer science traditionally are upside-down trees.  We should really be calling them roots, but the term trees has stuck.

So, the root is the topmost level, and the leaves are the lowermost levels.  Go figure.

(No computer scientist was ever famous for his grasp of the real world.)

Comment: http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~breech/contest.inet.fall.01/problems/bin-tree-level.html can you make any conclusion using this article

Comment: LOL! well, in this article they use upside down trees, but they do not use the term "low" or "lowest".  They speak of maximum level and last level, meaning that it has the highest designated level number, but is visually lowest.